# Scala: Create custom OptionT monad from cats for learning

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers, scala-cats

we are creating our own `OptionT` of cats for understanding, how monads are work and monads transformation flow. While creating our own custom monad getting some of the errors. First thing below is our code:

```
case class WhateverOpt[W[_], A] (value: W[Option[A]]) {

    def map[B] (f: A => B) (implicit M: Monad[W]): WhateverOpt[W, B] =
      WhateverOpt(M.map(value)(_.map(f)))

    def flatMap[B] (f: A => WhateverOpt[W, B]) (implicit M: Monad[W]): WhateverOpt[W, B] =
      WhateverOpt(M.flatMap(value)(optA => optA match {
        case Some(v) => f(v).value
      }))
  }

  implicit val optionTMonad = new Monad[Option] {

    override def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)
    override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
  }

  val optionResult = for {
    user <- WhateverOpt(repository.getUserOption(1))
    addres <- WhateverOpt(repository.getAddressOption(user))
  } yield addres.city
```

Below are the points, where we stuck:

1. How to handle None case in `WhateverOpt` `flatMap` method?
2. When executing the code, getting runtime error: 
   `Error:(26, 12) could not find implicit value for parameter M: usercases.mtransfomer.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future]
   addres <- WhateverOpt(repository.getAddressOption(user))`

We are not sure about the error because we are creating `optionTMonad` implicit and by default, all are in the same scope.  How can we resolve these two issues?

**Update**

Full code is available on Github branch https://github.com/harmeetsingh0013/fp_scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/usercases/mtransfomer/Example5.scala

Comment: Link does not seem to work, github gives 404 and a jedi-octocat.

Comment: Thanks, @AndreyTyukin you can check now.

Answer (score 1):

> How to handle None case in WhateverOpt flatMap method?

When you `flatMap` over `None` you return `None`. When you `flatMap` over `WhateverOpt[W[_], B]` you want to return the `pure` of it, which in your code would be `M.pure(None)`.

> When executing the code, getting runtime error:  `Error:(26, 12) could not find implicit value for parameter M: usercases.mtransfomer.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future]
>   addres <- WhateverOpt(repository.getAddressOption(user))`

That's a compile-time error (not a runtime one) and it's due to the missing instance of `Monad[Future]`. In order to get an instance of `Monad[Future]` in scope with cats, you can do:

```
import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Also, you can avoid declaring your own `Monad[Option]` by importing it from cats with

```
import cats.instances.option._
```

Comment: Hello @Gabriele, After importing `import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` this statements same error is occurring. Actually, IntelliJ does not show an error, during writing the code, that's why I thought, It is the runtime error.

Comment: Hello @Gabriele I found the answer, we need to declare `Monad[Future]` rather than, `Monad[Option]` because, we knew the `Option` is being a part of our custom `WhateverOpt` but, Future is decided by generics, that's why, in that case, we need to define the `Monad[Future]` for implicit resolution.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella `None` is the pure of `Option`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin woops, actually nope :)

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara `Monad[Future]` where?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella please check I am mention, in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

About how to deal with `None`:

```
case class WhateverOpt[W[_], A] (value: W[Option[A]]) {

  def map[B] (f: A => B) (implicit M: Monad[W]): WhateverOpt[W, B] =
    WhateverOpt(M.map(value)(_.map(f)))

  def flatMap[B] 
    (f: A => WhateverOpt[W, B])
    (implicit wMonad: Monad[W])
  : WhateverOpt[W, B] = {
    WhateverOpt(wMonad.flatMap(value) { (oa: Option[A]) => 
      oa match {
        case None => wMonad.pure(None)
        case Some(a) => f(a).value
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Imagine for a second that `W` is `Future`. Then the above code says:

- wait until the wrapped `value` yields a result `oa` of type `Option[A]`
- If `oa` turns out to be `None`, then there is nothing we can do, because we cannot obtain any instances of type `A` in order to call `f`. Therefore, immediately return `None`. The `immediately return` is the `pure`-method of the `Future`-monad, so for the general case we have to invoke `wMonad.pure(None)`.
- If `oa` yields `Some(a)`, we can give this `a` to `f`, and then immediately unpack it to get to the `value` of type `W[Option[B]]`.
- Once we have the `W[Option[B]]` (whether `empty` or not), we can wrap it into `WhateverOpt` and return from the `flatMap` method.

---

I assume that you wanted to reimplement `Monad[Option]` just for fun (it's already [in the library](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/package$$option$.html) (the `catsStdInstancesForOption` thing is a `CommutativeMonad`), but here is how you could re-build it:

```
implicit val optionTMonad = new Monad[Option] {
  override def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)
  def flatMap[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
  def pure[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)
  def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: (A) => Option[Either[A, B]]): Option[B] = {
    f(a) match {
      case Some(Left(nextA)) => tailRecM(nextA)(f)
      case Some(Right(res)) => Some(res)
      case None => None
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that 1.0.1 requires to implement `pure` and `tailRecM`, and does not provide default implementations for that.

---

I don't want to say much about the necessary imports for `future`, but the latest version has [cats.instances.future](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/package$$future$.html) which provides a `Monad` instance. Check this again, because it seems as if you are using a different version of cats (your version didn't complain because of the missing `tailRecM` in your `Option`-monad).

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey, for an answer with explanation. This is really helpful for learning more. But according to my code and requirements rather than `new Monad[Option]` we need to implement `new Monad[Future]` because, we know that `WhateverOpt` contains `Option` values, but `Future` is handled by generic parameter `W` that's why, we need to create `new Monad[Future]`. For more details, please look into GitHub code.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara Implementing a `Monad[Future]` wouldn't be too difficult, because `Future` already implements `flatMap` (that's the difficult part). But as I said in the answer: it should be enough to `import cats.instances.future._` to get the `catsStdInstancesForFuture`, which is the `Monad` that you want.

Comment: Actually @Anrey I am not much familar with `cats` library, for learning perspective I am impelemnting my own `Monad` trait and custom `OptionT` monad. But yes definatley, whenever I will going to explore `cats` library, your suggestions would help us.

Answer (score 1):

> How to handle None case in WhateverOpt flatMap method?

This answer is already explained by **@Gabriele Petronella** and **@Andrey Tyukin** with details.

> When executing the code, getting runtime error: Error:(26, 12) could
>   not find implicit value for parameter M:
>   usercases.mtransfomer.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future] addres <-
>   WhateverOpt(repository.getAddressOption(user))

This error occurs, because In `WhateverOpt` constructor we know that our value is `W[Option[A]]`, where `Option` is already defined and handle by the code, but `repository.getUserOption(1)` return `Future[Option[User]]` where `Future` is handled by generic parameter `W` and in that, case, we need to define, how to handle monads for `Future`. For resolving that issue, we need to implement `new Monad[Future]` rather than, `new Monad[Option]` as below:

```
case class WhateverOpt[W[_], A] (value: W[Option[A]]) {

    def map[B] (f: A => B) (implicit M: Monad[W]): WhateverOpt[W, B] =
      WhateverOpt(M.map(value)(_.map(f)))

    def flatMap[B] (f: A => WhateverOpt[W, B]) (implicit M: Monad[W]): WhateverOpt[W, B] =
      WhateverOpt(M.flatMap(value)(optA => optA match {
        case Some(v) => f(v).value
        case None => M.pure(None)
      }))
  }

  implicit val futureMonad = new Monad[Future] {
    override def pure[A](a: A): Future[A] = Future.successful(a)

    override def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => B): Future[B] = fa.map(f)

    override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => Future[B]): Future[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
  }

  val optionResult: WhateverOpt[Future, String] = for {
    user <- WhateverOpt(repository.getUserOption(1))
    addres <- WhateverOpt(repository.getAddressOption(user))
  } yield addres.city
```

I am not sure about my disription, which I mention in answere, but current my assumptions are this and for me above code is working fine. For a complete example, please click on the GitHub repo, which is mention in the question.